# 12.10 nvidia Geforce gt650m support?

Tags: nvidia

Is ubuntu 12.10 giving nvidia gt650m support?

I have installed the nvidia-current drivers and adjusted the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. 
The computer starts and I could sign in. But the Unity desktop was unusable because the Dash and Launcher are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

NVidia GForce have limited support on most Operating Systems.

One way you can do is Sign in, Sign out, Then use Classic gnome and it will most likely work.

Another way is that you can re-install Ubuntu with a LiveCD `.iso` or on Windows with the Ubuntu Installer called Wubi.exe.

There are other ways but I personally do not know them, I hope this can atleast give you a start of what to look for.